# Select Random line from Text File and display on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was creating a form which contains contact details on unity for a game. I managed to connect text file with unity and write lines to it but I am not sure how to get a random person from text file and display it on unity. If someone has any idea about this please help me out..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you link your file via e.g

```
public TextAsset file;
```

then you could e.g. do

```
private string GetRandomLine()
{
    var lines = file.text.Split('/n');

    var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lines.Length);

    return lines[randomIndex];
}
```

Or if you use system FileIo you can do

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lines.Length);

return lines[randomIndex];
```

---

Of course you might want to cache the file content and lines somewhere etc but I hope the idea gets clear.